# I cannot install Skype on Ubuntu 12.04 - 64bit

Tags: skype

[output by usc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FajGX.png)I tried installing Skype by using two methods: **Synaptic** and **Ubuntu Software Center**, but it shows an error and it's not working.

[image: skype install ubuntu error]

Comment: Do you have all repositories enabled in Software & Updates?

Answer (score 1):

For skype installation, if your system is 64 bit you need to enable 32 bit support. To enable multi-arch support, run the following commands in the terminal. *Note: if you have already done that then no need to run this*

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y ia32-libs
```

Then download skype from their [website for Ubuntu 12.04 multiarch.deb](https://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb). The latest skype version (4.3.0.37) has some bug fixes and updates.

After downloading, open the terminal and go where the deb has been downloaded:

```
cd /path/to/directory/
```

Install the skype deb file:

```
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

Install the missing dependecies:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

That's it.

Comment: can u give another idea?

Comment: i hv added output shown by usc

Comment: Try running *sudo apt-get install -y ia32-libs* and then follow the steps again.

Comment: not workin terminal writes ( u hv held broken package)

Comment: Screenshot of the terminal o/p

Comment: hw cn i send u screensot?

Comment: If u trust contact me via email. *support@sagarblog.com*

Comment: ok i hv send an email